# fixed positioning not working

Tags: jquery, css

i have this code where i want to position the nav bar at the top of the browser window when window is scrolled down by a certain amount.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

   $(window).scroll(function (){
     if($(this).scrollTop()>300)
      {
       $("#main_nav").css("position","fixed", "top", "0", "left", "initial");
      }
  });        
 });
```

but on window scroll, the nav bar remains at the same position vertically (top!=0) and horizontally moves to the begining of the browser window (left=0). can anyone tell me what's wrong with the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass all css properties as a JS object.
Use this line:

```
$("#main_nav").css({"position":"fixed", "top": "0", "left": "initial"});
```

When you need to set only one property value, you can do it without JS object.

```
$("#main_nav").css("position","fixed");
$("#main_nav").css("top", "0");
$("#main_nav").css("left", "initial");
```

or

```
$("#main_nav").css("position","fixed").css("top", "0").css("left", "initial");
```